# Get Highest and lowest value in input textbox and place value result textbox

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to get the Runner Time from the text box and place the results in the result textbox in descending order. The order should be 1st place, 2nd place, and 3rd place. I've tried using conditional statements but seems like I will have to use alot of code. Is there another way to figure out how to determine the 1st place, 2nd place and 3rd place.. Here is my code.

```
namespace Calculate Runner Time
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Calculatebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string Runner1Name;
            string Runner2Name;
            string Runner3Name;

            double Runner1Time;
            double Runner2Time;
            double Runner3Time;

            //double FirstPlace;
            //double SecondPlace;
            //double ThirdPlace;

          //get runner names
            Runner1Name = Runner1NametextBox.Text;
            Runner2Name = Runner2NametextBox.Text;
            Runner3Name = Runner3NametextBox.Text;



            //check if Runner1Name is empty 
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Runner1Name))
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("The Runner 1 Name cannot be empty ", "Invalid Runner Name",
                 MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            //check if Runner1Name is empty 
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Runner2Name)) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The Runner 2 Name cannot be empty ", "Invalid Runner Name",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Runner3Name))
            {
               MessageBox.Show("The Runner 3 Name cannot be empty ", "Invalid Runner Name",
               MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            else if (!double.TryParse(Runner1TimetextBox.Text, out Runner1Time)) 

            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Input a Positive number for Runner 1", "Invalid Input",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            else if  (!double.TryParse(Runner2TimetextBox.Text, out Runner2Time))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Input a Positive number for Runner 2", "Invalid Input",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            else if  (!double.TryParse(Runner3TimetextBox.Text, out Runner3Time))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Input a Positive number for Runner 3", "Invalid Input",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            //else if (Runner1Time == Runner2Time & Runner1Time == Runner3Time)
            //{
            //    FirstPlacetextBox.Text = Runner1Name.ToString();
            //    FirstPlacetextBox.Text = Runner2Name.ToString();
            //    FirstPlacetextBox.Text = Runner3Name.ToString();
            //}

            else if (Runner1Time >= Runner2Time & Runner1Time >= Runner3Time)              
            {
                FirstPlacetextBox.Text = Runner1Name.ToString();                         
            }

            else if (Runner2Time >= Runner1Time & Runner2Time >= Runner3Time)
            {
                FirstPlacetextBox.Text = Runner2Name.ToString();
            }

            else if  (Runner3Time >= Runner2Time & Runner3Time >= Runner1Time)
            {
                FirstPlacetextBox.Text = Runner3Name.ToString();
            }

            else if (Runner1Time <= Runner2Time & Runner1Time <= Runner3Time)
            {           

                SecondPlacetextBox.Text = Runner1Name.ToString();
            }

            else if (Runner2Time <= Runner1Time & Runner2Time <= Runner3Time)
            {
                SecondPlacetextBox.Text = Runner2Name.ToString();
            }

            else if (Runner3Time <= Runner2Time & Runner3Time <= Runner1Time)
            {
                SecondPlacetextBox.Text = Runner3Name.ToString();
            }

          //  else if ()
            {

            }
        }

        private void Closebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void Resetbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //clear runnername textboxes 
            Runner1NametextBox.Text = string.Empty;
            Runner2NametextBox.Text = string.Empty;
            Runner3NametextBox.Text = string.Empty;


            //clear runnertime 
            Runner1TimetextBox.Text = "";
            Runner2TimetextBox.Text = "";
            Runner3TimetextBox.Text = "";


            //clears result textbox 
            FirstPlacetextBox.Text = "";
            SecondPlacetextBox.Text = "";
            ThirdPlacetextBox.Text = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
Dictionary<string, double> results = new Dictionary<string, double>();

// Add your runners.
results.Add(Runner1Name, Runner1Time);
results.Add(Runner2Name , Runner2Time);
results.Add(Runner3Name , Runner2Time);

var bestTime = results.Min(item => item.Value);
var worstTime = results.Max(item => item.Value);
foreach (var item in results)
{
    if (item.Value == bestTime)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"First place {item.Key}");
        continue;
    }
    if (item.Value == worstTime)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Third place {item.Key}");
        continue;
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Second place {item.Key}");
}
```

Your function code:

```
private void Calculatebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Runner1Name;
    string Runner2Name;
    string Runner3Name;

    double Runner1Time;
    double Runner2Time;
    double Runner3Time;

    //double FirstPlace;
    //double SecondPlace;
    //double ThirdPlace;

  //get runner names
    Runner1Name = Runner1NametextBox.Text;
    Runner2Name = Runner2NametextBox.Text;
    Runner3Name = Runner3NametextBox.Text;



    //check if Runner1Name is empty 
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Runner1Name))
    {
         MessageBox.Show("The Runner 1 Name cannot be empty ", "Invalid Runner Name",
         MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    //check if Runner1Name is empty 
    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Runner2Name)) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The Runner 2 Name cannot be empty ", "Invalid Runner Name",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Runner3Name))
    {
       MessageBox.Show("The Runner 3 Name cannot be empty ", "Invalid Runner Name",
       MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    else if (!double.TryParse(Runner1TimetextBox.Text, out Runner1Time)) 

    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Input a Positive number for Runner 1", "Invalid Input",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    else if  (!double.TryParse(Runner2TimetextBox.Text, out Runner2Time))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Input a Positive number for Runner 2", "Invalid Input",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    else if  (!double.TryParse(Runner3TimetextBox.Text, out Runner3Time))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Input a Positive number for Runner 3", "Invalid Input",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    Dictionary<string, double> results = new Dictionary<string, double>();

    results.Add(Runner1Name, Runner1Time);
    results.Add(Runner2Name , Runner2Time);
    results.Add(Runner3Name , Runner2Time);

    var bestTime = results.Min(item => item.Value);
    var worstTime = results.Max(item => item.Value);
    foreach (var item in results)
    {
        if (item.Value == bestTime)
        {
            FirstPlacetextBox.Text = item.Key;
            continue;
        }
        if (item.Value == worstTime)
        {
            ThirdPlacetextBox.Text = item.Key;
            continue;
        }
        SecondPlacetextBox.Text = item.Key;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Response. I'm working on a windows form and i want to display the results in a label so I wouldn't have to use   "Console.WriteLine($"First place {item.Key}");" So i'm not sure how to do that any ideas?   @Dmitry Pokhlebaev

Comment: You can use your FirstPlacetextBox, SecondPlacetextBox etc instead of Console. For instance "FirstPlacetextBox.Text = string.Format($"First place {item.key}");"

Comment: note that I've changed two lines of my code: 
var bestTime = results.Min(item => item.Value);
var worstTime = results.Max(item => item.Value);

Comment: I did that and I'm still getting an error. "FirstPlacetextBox.Text = string.Format($"First Place {item.Key}");". What If i want to get the name of the runner with the highest run time?

Comment: What error did you get? Try to use this syntax:  FirstPlacetextBox.Text = string.Format("First Place {0}", item.Key);

Comment: Check out the code above. I've added your function to my response. If you don't have ThirdPlacetextBox just remove the line with it.